# Making a match-and-append code more efficient without 'for' loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to match 1<sup>st</sup> column of `A` with 1st to 3<sup>rd</sup> columns of `B`, and append corresponding 4<sup>th</sup> column of `B` to `A`.

For example,

```
A=
    1 2 
    3 4

B=
    1 2 4 5 4
    1 2 3 5 3
    1 1 1 1 2
    3 4 5 6 5
```

I compare `A(:,1)` and `B(:, 1:3)`

`1` and `3` are in `A(:,1)`

`1` is in the 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> rows of `B(:, 1:3)`, so append `B([1 2 3], 4:end)'`  to `A`'s 1<sup>st</sup> row.
`3` is in the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> rows of `B(:,1:3)`, so append `B([2 4], 4:end)'` to `A`'s 2<sup>nd</sup> row.

So that it becomes:

```
1 2 5 4 5 3 1 2
3 4 5 3 6 5 0 0
```

I could code this using only `for` and `if`.

```
clearvars AA A B mem mem2 mem3

A = [1 2 ; 3 4]
B = [1 2 4 5 4; 1 2 3 5 3; 1 1 1 1 2; 3 4 5 6 5]

for n=1:1:size(A,1)
    mem  = ismember(B(:,[1:3]), A(n,1));
    mem2 = mem(:,1) + mem(:,2) + mem(:,3);
    mem3 = find(mem2>0);

    AA{n,:} = horzcat( A(n,:), reshape(B(mem3,[4,5])',1,[]) );  %'
end

maxLength = max(cellfun(@(x)numel(x),AA));
out = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)cat(2,x,zeros(1,maxLength-length(x))),AA,'UniformOutput',false))
```

I am trying to make this code efficient, by not using `for` and `if`, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Can there be zeros in `A` or `B`?

Comment: in your definition of `AA` (last line inside loop) you should use `4:end` instead of `[4,5]`. ANd your code runs quite fast/efficient. Would recommend to keep it, if no faster solution is found... there is no reason to avoid loops just that many times there is a faster solution without loops.

Comment: @TheMinion: there is the problem that his loop body contains `ismember`, which means JIT cannot accelerate this loop effectively. For larger problems, this will becomes a concern.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis True. Hence the problem isn't the `for-loop` but the `ismember()` inside the loop. Still when I ran his code and the one from Nishant, his was minimal faster even for 10.000x100 entries. So not sure if that "problem" with `ismember()` really results in such runtime issues. BTW nice solution +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = A(:,1);
b = B(:,1:3);
z = size(b);
b = repmat(b,[1,1,numel(a)]);
ab = repmat(permute(a,[2,3,1]),z);
row2 = mat2cell(permute(sum(ab==b,2),[3,1,2]),ones(1,numel(a)));
AA = cellfun(@(x)(reshape(B(x>0,4:end)',1,numel(B(x>0,4:end)))),row2,'UniformOutput',0);
maxLength = max(cellfun(@(x)numel(x),AA));
out = cat(2,A,cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)cat(2,x,zeros(1,maxLength-length(x))),AA,'UniformOutput',false)))
```

**UPDATE** Below code runs in almost same time as the iterative code

```
a = A(:,1);
b = B(:,1:3);
z = size(b);
b = repmat(b,[1,1,numel(a)]);
ab = repmat(permute(a,[2,3,1]),z);
df = permute(sum(ab==b,2),[3,1,2])';
AA = arrayfun(@(x)(B(df(:,x)>0,4:end)),1:size(df,2),'UniformOutput',0);
AA = arrayfun(@(x)(reshape(AA{1,x}',1,numel(AA{1,x}))),1:size(AA,2),'UniformOutput',0);    
maxLength = max(arrayfun(@(x)(numel(AA{1,x})),1:size(AA,2)));
out2 = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,i)((cat(2,A(i,:),AA{1,x},zeros(1,maxLength-length(AA{1,x}))))),1:numel(AA),1:size(A,1),'UniformOutput',0));
```

Comment: Well done finding the solution, but when checking runtime (running the code a 1000 times) it takes about 2 secs, while the `for, if` solution by OP takes only 1.5 secs.

Comment: @Nishant Thank you! Although as Minion said it did not improve speed much I could learn a lot about repmat.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
%# example data
A = [1 2
     3 4];

B = [1 2 4 5 4
     1 2 3 5 3
     1 1 1 1 2
     3 4 5 6 5];

%# rename for clarity & reshape for algorithm's convenience
needle   = permute(A(:,1), [2 3 1]);
haystack = B(:,1:3);
data     = B(:,4:end).';

%# Get the relevant rows of 'haystack' for each entry in 'needle'
inds = any(bsxfun(@eq, haystack, needle), 2);

%# Create data that should be appended to A
%# All data and functionality in this loop is local and static, so speed 
%# should be optimal.
append = zeros( size(A,1), numel(data) );
for ii = 1:size(inds,3)    
    newrow = data(:,inds(:,:,ii));
    append(ii,1:numel(newrow)) = newrow(:);    
end

%# Now append to A, stripping unneeded zeros
A = [A append(:, ~all(append==0,1))]
```